# Run PHP to pull google sheets CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, google-sheets

im working with the code below, it works in a regular php document but when i use it in wordpress it doesnt work. i have a plugin installed to allow me to run php code on pages. any help is appreciated.

```
<?PHP
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oC88LWXn4SgvVzK3wQAojXk7UM5tDjuWuMZDAjQTGjw/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
?>
<?php

print_r($csv[0][1]);//prints row 1, column 1

?> <?php

print_r($csv[0][2]);//prints row 1, column 1

?>
```

Comment: What seems to go wrong? Are any errors logged?

Answer (score 0):

Your `fopen` function makes a call to an external document.

It's very common for shared hosting providers to disable `allow_url_fopen` in `php.ini` to stop `Remote File Inclusion` attacks.

You need to instead use `cURL` to get the data back. Here's an illustration. I've chosen to use the `php://temp` stream to store the data returned, as we don't need it locally. This will allow us to read from the stream pointer and then loop it, pushing each line into the `$line_of_text[]` array.

```
function readCSV($url){
    $fh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh); 
    curl_close($ch);      

    rewind($fh);

    while ($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1024)) {
        $line_of_text[] = $line;
    }

    fclose($f);

    return $line_of_text;
}
```

**Alternative and less recommended solution**

Find and locate the loaded `php.ini` for your site, and modify `allow_url_fopen` to `1`.

Comment: used your code and got this error     "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘}’ in /home/advancedstorage/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/insert_php.php(48) : eval()’d code on line 13"

Comment: @Eli Sorry. I'd missed a semicolon after `$line` it's corrected now.

Comment: thanks @ohgodwhy, i got it working, but the only thing that isnt working is that wordpress isnt showing print_r($csv[0][1]);